# Terminate Spring Boot Task on any Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot task application which has operations including:

1. Reading data from DB
2. Processing
3. Sending to MQ

I am using 10 threads which run these 3 operations in parallel. I would like my application to terminate once an exception occurs in any thread.

Any suggestion as to how can I achieve this functionality?

`System.exit(0)` does not seem to work with multiple threads.

Answer (score -1):

One possible way to shutdown would be to shutdown your task executor (how to do that depends on your configuration), which in turn should set the interrupt flag on your task threads. Then it is your responsibility to check interrupt flag and stop the task processing.

If you want to forcefully halt the JVM, you can call [Runtime#halt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt(int)).